# Why can't I require a gem from within the .gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I can't require third party code in my .gemspec file. I would like to require a semver library to manage my version number. Why can't I require gems inside my .gemspec?

I have a workaround for my particular problem. What I am interested in the specific reason I can't require code from inside a gemspec. I feel like I am missing something about how Rubygems work. Thanks!

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'semver'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.add_dependency "semver2", "~> 3.4.2"
  spec.version       = SemVer.find.to_s[1..-1]
end
```

## Running bundle install results in the following error:

```
$ bundle

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: There was a LoadError while loading example.gemspec: 
cannot load such file -- semver from
  /opt/pose/auto/stack-overflow/example/example.gemspec:3:in `<main>'
```

Obviously there is some point before which you cannot depend on 3rd party gems to be on your LOAD_PATH. I am asking for an explanation of where that point is. My guess is because my Gemfile references my gemspec and Bundler had not loaded all the dependencies yet, but that is a guess.

Comment: What do you mean by “require code”? Sources? Because to require 3rd party gems is likely the main and only goal of `.gemspec`.

Comment: Are you confusing declaring dependencies and actually requiring code?

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564195/how-can-i-install-a-gem-via-bundler-using-gemspec-before-parsing-the-gemspec

Answer (score 1):

A `.gemspec` is just a Ruby script like any other Ruby script. Basically the only thing that is "special" is that it is run in an environment where certain libraries have already been `require`d, such as `rubygems/specification`.

`require`ing libraries works just like in any other Ruby script.

Comment: You're right that `require` works. My question has been revised to emphasize that, in the gemspec file, you cannot depend on those gems to be on the load path, or even installed.